# Unable to consume WCF service by Java Script using XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, wcf, rest, xmlhttprequest

Here is my java script to call WCF service

```
 function CallWcfAjax() {
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

           var url = "http://localhost:20949/RestService/tiger/pandey";                    

           // Send the HTTP request
           xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
           xmlhttp.send();           

           // Create result handler 
           xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function X() {                   
               if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                   alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
               }
           }
       }
```

if I enter the same URL in browser http://localhost:20949/RestService/tiger/pandey i get a response.

Any idea what wrong I am doing in Java Script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You variable name is xmlhttp and in the rest of you code, you use xmlHttp. This is a problem.

Comment: Thanks , I corrected that but still I am getting null in xmlhttp.responseXML and blank value in xmlhttp.responseText

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your service then because I've just tried this exact same javascript code with a WCF REST API and it works fine...

Comment: Now that I think about it, is your web page on the same server as your API? You might have a cross domain origin policies error : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy